# Hide dashed line border on FlipView in Windows Store App

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, flipview

In my Windows Store App, when I press the arrow buttons on the keyboard to go to the next or previous item in my FlipView, a dashed line border appears around the FlipView to indicate that it has focus. This looks ugly and serves no purpose in my app. It looks like this border is hidden in other apps that I have looked at.

The SelectionBorderVisibility property is not available in WinRT. I was able to hide the border by defining a custom FlipView style and setting the Stroke property inside one of the rectangle to null as follows.

```
<Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualWhite" IsHitTestVisible="False" Opacity="0" StrokeDashOffset="1" StrokeEndLineCap="Square" Stroke="{x:Null}" StrokeDashArray="1,1"/>
```

However, I'd rather not have to define an entire custom FlipView style if possible. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: It's there for keyboard nav, you can either just go remove it and its storyboards from that VisualState, or style it how you wish. Either way just do it at the default style template and you're done with it.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I ended up doing.